# Django: python manage.py migrate does nothing at all

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-3.5

I just started learning django, and as i try to apply my migrations the first problem occurs. I start the server up, type

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and nothing happens. No error, no crash, just no response.

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 13 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

May 01, 2017 - 11:36:27
Django version 1.11, using settings 'website.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
python manage.py migrate
```

And that's the end of my terminal feed.
I thought maybe it just looks like nothing happens, but no. The changes weren't applied and I can't proceed any further. Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: Did you run ``makemigrations`` first?

Comment: Yup. Both give no response.

Comment: Do you have multiple databases?

Comment: Just the standard db.sqlite3 provided by django.

Comment: Can you see your app and migrations in ``manage.py showmigrations``?

Comment: Same thing, no response

Comment: You did not answer my question :)

Comment: I thought you wanted me to call python manage.py showmigrations? Otherwise there's no such function inside of the manage.py file.

Comment: Did you make your own ``manage.py`` or something? I hope you are using the one Django generated for you. It should just pass in the command line arguments to django.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using django's manage.py and manage.py runserver works just like it should ,everything regarding migrations seems to give no answer. So yeah, i cant see anything popping up in my command line.

Comment: Can you include your database settings?

Comment: I haven't yet changed anything from the basic db.sqlite3 django gives you. To be fair, I don't even know how to work with the database yet since I'm still trying to work this migration out.

Comment: That being said, I think you might be looking for this:

   DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }

Comment: I think @PierreOcinom is on to something in the answers.

Comment: If not, if you'd be so kind to direct me to where I can get that info from, that'd be awesome.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Grimmy! It's solved indeed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you say that you first start the server and then type in the commands. That's also what the terminal feed you shared shows.

Do not run the server if you want to run management commands using `manage.py`.

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit the server and then run your migration commands, it will work.

Comment: Oh. That's obvious and I hadn't even checked... It works. Thanks, and thanks @Grimmy for trying to help the best you could.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Same result. Both give no response.

Comment: @AmiralJion you are just guessing the answer base on a lot of assumptions here. Not the right way to go.

Comment: So, some other newbies might make the same mistake as me, thus mentioning this here. Make sure whether your project is running on python 2.7 or python3. If its python3, run the commands in this answer with python3 i.e. python3 manage.py makemigrations

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error 
running this 2 command in terminal

```
    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate
```

and then

```
    python manage.py runserver
```

solved my issues.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

@adam-karolczak n all

If there are multiple DJANGO Projects, it can happen that DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is set to some other app in environment varibles, the current project manage.py will not point to current project settings thus the error.

So, confirm DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in fact points to the settings.py of current project.

Close the project if its running viz. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. 
You can also check the server is not running ( linux ) by

```
ps -ef | grep runserver
```

Then kill the process ids if they exist.
If you confirmed settings.py in DJANGO_MODULE_SETTINGS is for the project you are having issue.
Run the following it should resolve.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with  parameter?

`python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>`

Comment: No response from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was that there was a pg_dump script running at the same time I was trying to migrate. After the dump was completed, migrations ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

- Check that INSTALL_APPS app exists, if not add it
- Checks the model for default attributes
- Running this 2 command in terminal

  `python manage.py makemigrations`
  `python manage.py migration`

Answer (score 0):

1. First exit of the present web server by typing `Ctrl + C`
2. Then run `python manage.py migrate`

The Warning is due to not configuring the initial database or migrating.

Answer (score 0):

for Collab try following command

```
!python manage.py makemigrations  #for creating new migrations based on the changes you have made to your models.
!python manage.py migrate
followed by
!python manage.py migrate runserver
```